# Extracting group data PySpark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have loaded the following data into DataFrame as below

```
S.NO  routename        status      tripcount

1      East           STARTED      1
2      West           STARTED      1
4      East           ARRIVED      2
5      East           ARRIVED      3
6      East           STARTED      4 
7      East           STARTED      5 
8      West           ARRIVED      2
9      East           ARRIVED      6
```

I want to take out only the following rows

1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9

Basically STARTED - ARRIVED base rest of them I want to skip. Now I have loaded

```
dataframe_mysql.select("routename").distinct().show()
```

With this should I have to loop inside lambda expression or is there any other inbuilt method will help me to get the result.

Comment: can you explain your logic a little bit more?

Comment: I want to take every first STARTED and next first ARRIVED for each route name. 1 - 4, 2 - 8, 6 - 9. If same status repeated then it should be skipped.

Comment: Can I group it by routename and execute independently ?

Comment: yes definitely, and that would make you processing in spark worthy enough. :) glad that you figured it out

Comment: Could you please tell me - how to skip the records when I encounter same status? Can I use loop inside lambda or any other option?

Comment: Thats where im stuck. I want to gothrough (scan) every record and take out in sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can benefit by using `Window` and `lag` functions. And you can use `fillna`, `filter` and `drop` functions to get your desired result.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W
windowSpec = W.partitionBy("routename").orderBy(F.col("S_NO"))

df.withColumnRenamed("S.NO", "S_NO").withColumn("remove", F.lag("status", 1).over(windowSpec))\
    .fillna({"remove":"nullString"})\
    .filter(F.col("status") != F.col("remove"))\
    .drop("remove")
```

Here we are grouping the `Window` function with `routename` column and ordering by `S_NO`. `S.NO` is renamed as it was creating problem after `fillna` function. `lag` function will copy `status` from *previous status* to new column `remove`. `fillna` will replace all *null values* to *nullString StringType* so that it can be considered in `filter`. Finally `remove` column is `drop`ped.

If you want the output sorted you can use additional orderBy

```
.orderBy("S_NO")
```

And you should get output as

```
+----+---------+-------+---------+
|S_NO|routename|status |tripcount|
+----+---------+-------+---------+
|1   |East     |STARTED|1        |
|2   |West     |STARTED|1        |
|4   |East     |ARRIVED|2        |
|6   |East     |STARTED|4        |
|8   |West     |ARRIVED|2        |
|9   |East     |ARRIVED|6        |
+----+---------+-------+---------+
```

Hope the answer is more than helpful

**Update**

As @syv pointed out that `lag` has *default value parameter option* which can be used when value is not found for `lag` so that `fillna` function call can totally be removed and even the column renaming is not needed at all

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W
windowSpec = W.partitionBy("routename").orderBy(F.col("`S.NO`"))

df.withColumn("remove", F.lag("status", 1, "nullString").over(windowSpec))\
    .filter(F.col("status") != F.col("remove"))\
    .drop("remove")\
    .orderBy(F.col("`S.NO`"))
```

which should give you

```
+----+---------+-------+---------+
|S.NO|routename|status |tripcount|
+----+---------+-------+---------+
|1   |East     |STARTED|1        |
|2   |West     |STARTED|1        |
|4   |East     |ARRIVED|2        |
|6   |East     |STARTED|4        |
|8   |West     |ARRIVED|2        |
|9   |East     |ARRIVED|6        |
+----+---------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you , one question insted of .fillna({"remove":"nullString"}), Can I use "F.lag("status", 1 , "nullString") will it fill default value? I tried it in another case but it still shows null.

Comment: Yes @syv thats really great. I didn't know about that too. Try it and see it yourself and learn and teach other people. :)

Comment: This works !! "F.lag("status", default = "nullString")

Comment: @syv yes it works. thanks for sharing the knowledge and thanks for the acceptance and upvote

Comment: @syv more optimized answer is updated please have a look :)